# Add user to group automatically after registration in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I made this before with django like this:

signals/handlers.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from users.models import *

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        g1 = Group.objects.get(name='Editors')
        instance.groups.add(g1)
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class RegistrationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'registration'

    def ready(self):
        import registration.signals.handlers
```

but I don't know how to make it with wagtail !

thanks.

Comment: Wagtail uses Django's core permissions framework, so this logic should work. Are you sure that your signal handler is actually being registered? Where are you importing `signals/handlers`?

Comment: @solarissmoke thanks for your replay, I importing it in apps.py, I updated the question with apps.py file

Comment: Can you show us (a) your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and (b) the `__init__.py` in the registration app directory?

Comment: @solarissmoke you are genius, I forget to add this line `default_app_config = 'registration.apps.RegistrationConfig'` in `__init__.py` .. now it is working

Comment: @damar225 your comments helped me a lot thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using Django signals, Wagtail has `hooks` that simplify this for you. You can also send password reset email etc... after creating user using the same technique.

Just create a `wagtail_hooks.py` in your app:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from wagtail.core import hooks
    
@hooks.register('after_create_user')
def add_user_to_group(request, user):
    if user:
       group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Group Name')
       user.groups.add(group)
```

Docs: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html?highlight=after_create_user#id40

Comment: Poster wanted to do it using signals but you direct them to hooks instead, which is not appropriate for some application

Comment: OP wanted to do this in Wagtail which has those specific hooks built in.