# Programmatically creating permissions for pages and collections in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I'm wondering if anyone has examples of how to create permissions in Wagtail for collections and pages and then give specific users access to that role. I see how to create the Collections and AuthGroups easily, but I don't see how to specify the AuthGroup permissions in detail.

Edit:
In my case, the answer below in addition, to this bit of code for module permissions allowed for everything to be automatically added for a group:

```py
try:
  perm = course_group.permissions.get(codename=x.codename, content_type=x.content_type)
except Permission.DoesNotExist:
  perm_created = course_group.permissions.add(x)
```

Comment: Can anyone answer this? I cannot find anything documented for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some code like this in a population script. In this example, I want a group named `Team` to be able to add, change and choose wagtail images and documents in any collection. I also want them to be able to add, edit and publish any pages on the site. This example can hopefully be modified to suit another setup.

```py
from wagtail.models import Page
from wagtail.core.models import Collection, GroupCollectionPermission, GroupPagePermission
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

team_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Team')
if created:
    #This is only done once, when the group didn't already exist
    root_collection = Collection.get_first_root_node()
    GroupCollectionPermission.objects.create(group=team_group, collection=root_collection, permission=Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='wagtailimages', codename='add_image'))
    GroupCollectionPermission.objects.create(group=team_group, collection=root_collection, permission=Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='wagtailimages', codename='change_image'))
    GroupCollectionPermission.objects.create(group=team_group, collection=root_collection, permission=Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='wagtailimages', codename='choose_image'))

    GroupCollectionPermission.objects.create(group=team_group, collection=root_collection, permission=Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='wagtaildocs', codename='add_document'))
    GroupCollectionPermission.objects.create(group=team_group, collection=root_collection, permission=Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='wagtaildocs', codename='change_document'))
    GroupCollectionPermission.objects.create(group=team_group, collection=root_collection, permission=Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='wagtaildocs', codename='choose_document'))

    root_page = Page.objects.get(id=1)
    GroupPagePermission.objects.create(group=team_group, page=root_page, permission_type='add')
    GroupPagePermission.objects.create(group=team_group, page=root_page, permission_type='edit')
    GroupPagePermission.objects.create(group=team_group, page=root_page, permission_type='publish')
```

To find the available wagtail content types and list their identifiers, I ran

```py
for x in Permission.objects.order_by().values('content_type__app_label').distinct():
    print(x['content_type__app_label'])
```

To find the permission codenames of  a given content type, I ran

```py
for x in Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label='wagtailimages'):
    print(x.codename)
```

For the `GroupPagePermission` parameter `permission_type`, I found the options in the wagtail source. It lists these options:

```py
PAGE_PERMISSION_TYPES = [
    ('add', _("Add"), _("Add/edit pages you own")),
    ('edit', _("Edit"), _("Edit any page")),
    ('publish', _("Publish"), _("Publish any page")),
    ('bulk_delete', _("Bulk delete"), _("Delete pages with children")),
    ('lock', _("Lock"), _("Lock/unlock pages you've locked")),
    ('unlock', _("Unlock"), _("Unlock any page")),
]
```

In my project I'm not adding users to groups programmatically, but hopefully [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199323/add-user-to-group-automatically-after-registration-in-wagtail) helps